# Запуск AJAX только с определенного места

Tags: ajax, php

Есть страница на сайте, и хочу туда прикрутить AJAX запросы, но хочу немного обезопасить себя и сделать так чтобы AJAX запрос выполнялся только с определенной страницы, чтоб нельзя было обратиться на прямую. Возможно-ли такое реализовать?

Comment: Не подцепляйте js код с логикой ajax'a на те страницы, на которые вам это не нужно. Обезопасить от чего вы хотите себя таким образом?

Comment: ->чтоб нельзя было обратиться на прямую

Посылайте POST запрос вместо GET и уже в PHP проверяйте пустой ли POST или нет. Ну и выше код воткните, ток совсем не понятно чего вы хотите добиться.

Comment: Скорее всего ТС пытается закрыть возможность обращения к странице через Curl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Или пропишите код на той самой нужной странице, или проверяйте с помощью [location](http://javascript.ru/window-location)
2. Для того, чтоб сценарий обработчика реагировал только на ajax-запросы, можно сделать такое условие:

   ```
   if(isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) && ( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest' )){
       // обрабатываете ajax-запрос
   }
   ```